# How to display Last name in custom user profile in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to display the last name of all the user in user profile but I am able to display only the username.

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from commonpage.models import UserProfile,PositionTable

#register the above models
class user_action(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['user', 'useractive','position','team_name','preferd_shift']
ordering = ['id']
list_filter = ('useractive','position','team_name','preferd_shift')
list_editable = ['position','team_name','preferd_shift']
actions = [make_user_active,make_user_deactive]

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(UserProfile,user_action)
admin.site.register(PositionTable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use related fields directly in `list_display`, but you can point it at a method that returns the relevant field:

```
class user_action(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'last_name', ...]
    ...
    def last_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do that with `__` *(underscore)* + `field_name`.

```
list_display = ['user', 'user__last_name', 'useractive','position','team_name','preferd_shift']
```

Comment: I have tried it is giving the following error 

ERRORS:
<class 'commonpage.admin.user_action'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[1]' refers to 'user__last_name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'user_action', or an attribute or method on 'commonpage.UserProfile'.

Comment: please include your `models.py`